# Using the JSON data between jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

This code snippet gets a Json data from a API hosted in my localhost. I can get the json objects into their own css id(selector?) but I want to use value somewhere else in my javascript. For example, I want to use '#long' in my javascript. I tried using global variable but it says that 'long' is undefined. What do I have to do so that I can use uid, lat or long elsewhere in my script?

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("http://localhost:4567/get/233307/loc", function(data){
        $('#uid').append("UID: " + data.uid);
        $('#lat').append("Latitute: " + data.lat);
        $('#long').append("Longitude: " + data.long);

        var long = data.long;
        alert(long);
        }, "json");

});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myApp = {};
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("http://localhost:4567/get/233307/loc", function(data) {
       myApp.data = data; // Can be stored here.
       orPassItToAnotherFunction(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variables in the global scope, and assign them in the ajax callback.

```
var long;
var lat;
var uid;

$(document).ready(function(){

 $.get("http://localhost:4567/get/233307/loc", function(data){
    $('#uid').append("UID: " + data.uid);
    $('#lat').append("Latitute: " + data.lat);
    $('#long').append("Longitude: " + data.long);

    long = data.long;
    lat = data.lat;
    uid = data.uid;
    alert(long);
 }, "json");

});
```

Comment: you should prob enclose them in namespace though.

Comment: I have tried doing this but, if I try to use long, lat or uid in another function it has 'undefined' value.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `var long;` previously, outside `$(document).ready(function(){`